# Need to convert 16 bit data to 8 bit

Tags: c++, c, iconv, libiconv

```
int main()
{
    char str[200] = {0};
    char out[500] = {0};

    str[0]=0x00; str[1]=0x52; str[2]=0x00; str[3]=0x65; str[4]=0x00; str[5]=0x73; str[6]= 0x00; str[7]=0x74;

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(str);i++)
    cout<<"-"<<str[i];
    changeCharEncoding("UCS-2","ISO8859-1",str,out,sizeof(out));
    cout<<"\noutput : "<<out;
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(out);i++)
    cout<<":"<<out[i];
}

//encoding function
int changeCharEncoding(const char *from_charset, const char *to_charset, const char *input, char *output, int out_size)
{
    size_t input_len = 8;
    size_t output_len = out_size;
    iconv_t l_cd;
    if ((l_cd = iconv_open (to_charset, from_charset)) == (iconv_t) -1)
    {
            return -1;
    }
    int rc = iconv(l_cd, (char **)&input, &input_len, (char **)&output, &output_len);
    if (rc == -1)
    {
            iconv_close(l_cd);
            return -2;
    }
    else
    {
            iconv_close(l_cd);
    }
}
```

Please suggest me a method to convert 16 bit data to 8 bit.I have tried it using iconv. Also suggest me if there is something else to do the same.

Comment: By it's very definition this is going to be difficult. What are you going to do with your overflows? If you're converting character sets you'll need to be very sure of your source and target encodings, and you'll need a mechanism for handling out-of-set conversions.

Comment: What do you mean with "data"? And what do you mean with "convert", even? Are you trying to do ASCII representations of Unicode text?

Comment: Also, C **XOR** C++? Pick exactly one.

Comment: basically i have a string which is encoded in UCS2 and i need to convert it into utf-8, so for that i tried to develop the sample program and found that it is not working

Comment: the above program should print "Rest" as output

Comment: So, what *does* it output if it doesn't output "Rest"? and you go to much trouble to return error codes from changeCharEncoding, but you then ignore them completely...???

Comment: Are you sure your 16-bit chars should be encoded hi-order byte first? Try str[0] = 0x52, str[1] = 0, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert between `UTF-16` and `UTF-8` encoding:
Try changing your call of `changeCharEncoding()` to:

```
changeCharEncoding("UTF-16","UTF-8",str,out,sizeof(out));
```

The resulting `UTF-8` output should be

```
刀攀猀琀
```

On a sidenote: there are several things in your code that you should consider improving. For example both `changeCharEncoding` and `main` are declared to return an `int` whereas your implementation does not.

Comment: I think he wants it to be "Rest". Sounds like a BOM issue!

Comment: no the `UTF-16` input is `Rest` which when converted to `UTF-8` encoding yields the result I showed

Comment: Well, that's wrong, then. "Rest" in UTF-16 (or UCS-2) should be "Rest" in UTF-8 (or, ISO8859-1 for that matter)

Comment: OK you are probably right, that means his `changeCharEncoding` function is flawed then, as I have not checked its accuracy.

Comment: @Roddy: Pankrates correctly changes the input, and that input is *not* "Rest" -- it's "\u5200\u6500\u7300\u7400". The first character of Pankrates' output confrims this: [codepoint=5200](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=5200)

Comment: @Jongware - You are assuming one "little-endianness" for the string. The OP is assuming "big-endianness". UCS-2 is by definition always big-endian, (but in practice that's not always the case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2 ). I expect that by changing "UCS-2" to "UCS-2BE" he'l get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking - you cannot convert arbitrary 16 bit data into 8 bit data, you will loose some data

if you're trying to convert encodings - the same rule applies, as you cannot convert some symbols into 8bit ASCII, so they will be lost, for different platforms you can use different functions:

Windows: [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*nix: [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html)

Comment: i have used iconv in the above code but it is not working the same. And i know that some data will be lost so that is not the problem

Comment: why do you think its not working? is it memory fault, wrong results, empty results?

Comment: it should give "Rest" as output after converting it to 8 bit data

Comment: what is the rest? and why it should output it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have an endian-ness problem: Try changing this

```
changeCharEncoding("UCS-2","ISO8859-1",str,out,sizeof(out));
```

to this

```
changeCharEncoding("UCS-2BE","ISO8859-1",str,out,sizeof(out));
```